# How to deploy .net and nginx in kubernetes?

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, nginx

I have deployed .net + nginx in docker. 
When I try to go to http://myhost I see the 
[nginx default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U8uP.png) but not [my project page on .net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIMd7.png).

How can I fix this?

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - app
```

.net Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication4.dll"]
```

nginx

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  # Nginx will handle gzip compression of responses from the app server
  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain application/json;
  gzip_min_length 1000;

  server {
    listen 80;

    # Nginx will reject anything not matching /api
    location /api {
      # Reject requests with unsupported HTTP method
      if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE)$) {
        return 405;
      }

      # Only requests matching the whitelist expectations will
      # get sent to the application server
      proxy_pass http://172.28.0.3:5000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your `nginx.conf` will only proxy requests that match /api. Are you hitting a /api address or are you trying to hit the / root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for evreybody. I resolve my problem. In docker-compose need to add network_mode: 'host'

nginx:

network_mode: 'host'